# How can I solve this Invocation Exception error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, random-forest, decision-tree

when I run this code on jupyter notebook its showing an error.I have already installed graphviz and checked whether its properly installed or not(through this code I have tried to get the decision tree).But when I run this code its saying that,

**InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: 'C:\Users\Dilki' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Actually this path is wrong .The actual path is 'C:\Users\Dilki Thishaka'.I couldn't be able to rename the folder name(without the space) since this folder is the administrator folder.How can I fix this.Please help..

```
#Generate the decision tree
from six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()
tree = rnd_clf.estimators_[1] 
export_graphviz(tree, out_file=dot_data,feature_names = feature_list,rounded = True, precision = 1) 
 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[Here is the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFAAB.png)

Comment: Please edit your post to use code formatting. Even if you've already managed to solve the problem (good for you!), a nicer formatting may help others in the future, who encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with `pydot` on Windows.

The below fix steps are from this [issue](https://github.com/rsokl/MyGrad/issues/262#issue-663864011).

**1. Find dot.bat file in env**. E.g. at `C:\Users\Ryan S\.conda\envs\week3\Library\bin\dot.bat`

The original file will contain

`%~dp0.\graphviz\dot.exe %*`

**2. Add quotes**:

`"%~dp0.\graphviz\dot.exe" %*`
and save

Feel free to check the issue linked above and [this issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/graphviz-feedstock/issues/43) too, for more info.

**EDIT: Finding the environment**

You can find your environment location by running:

```
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
```

This will return something like: `C:\...\ENV_NAME`.
Then `dot.bat` should be in `C:\...\ENV_NAME\Library\bin\dot.bat`

Comment: Can you please explain this.How can I be able to find this dot.dat file

Comment: @user12864747 I added info in my answer on where `dot.bat` should be.

Comment: @user12864747 Glad I was able to help. Feel free to accept the answer as a solution. This helps other users that have the same issue to quickly find the solution.